# React js Nested Loop array

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, multidimensional-array, foreach

Hi I need nelp for following json array loop.it likes that instagram or facebook post. I have a json nested array. I tried below code but it is not helped me. I need the view like that instagram post Below attached image.

I want get Profile,Likes,Comments,Post details separately through loop

Output:(for ex. If loop through Record1 means it get all nested item like (profile,Post..etc)).It print output like below image

Records1 :
     Profile
     Post
     likedetails
     commentdetails
Records2 :
     Profile
     Post
     likedetails
     commentdetails
Records3 :
     Profile
     Post
     likedetails
     commentdetails
Records4 :
     Profile
     Post
     likedetails
     commentdetails
Records5 :
     Profile
     Post
     likedetails
     commentdetails

```
render() {
  var Json={
     "AllPost":[
        {
           "User_Id":1,
           "Username":"te",
           "Records":[
              {
                 "Profile":[{
                    "User_Id":"1",
                    "UserImage":"",
                    "Fullname":"Test",
                    "Username":"te"
                 }],
                 "Post":[{
                    "Post_Id":"1",
                    "UploadFile":"",
                    "Post_Caption":"Test",
                    "User_Id":"1"
                 }],
                 "likedetails":[{
                    "Post_Id":"1",
                    "LikeCount":"345"
                 }],
                 "commentdetails":[
                    {
                       "Comments":"testA",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testB",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testC",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testD",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testE",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    }
                 ]
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "User_Id":2,
           "Username":"te",
           "Records":[
              {
                 "Profile":[{
                    "User_Id":"2",
                    "UserImage":"",
                    "Fullname":"Test",
                    "Username":"te"
                 }],
                 "Post":[{
                    "Post_Id":"2",
                    "UploadFile":"",
                    "Post_Caption":"Test",
                    "User_Id":"2"
                 }],
                 "likedetails":[{
                    "Post_Id":"12",
                    "LikeCount":"3452"
                 }],
                 "commentdetails":[
                    {
                       "Comments":"testA",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testB",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testC",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testD",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testE",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    }
                 ]
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "User_Id":3,
           "Username":"te",
           "Records":[
              {
                 "Profile":[{
                    "User_Id":"3",
                    "UserImage":"",
                    "Fullname":"Test3",
                    "Username":"te3"
                 }],
                 "Post":[{
                    "Post_Id":"3",
                    "UploadFile":"",
                    "Post_Caption":"Test",
                    "User_Id":"3"
                 }],
                 "likedetails":[{
                    "Post_Id":"3",
                    "LikeCount":"345"
                 }],
                 "commentdetails":[
                    {
                       "Comments":"testA",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testB",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testC",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testD",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testE",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    }
                 ]
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "User_Id":4,
           "Username":"te",
           "Records":[
              {
                 "Profile":[{
                    "User_Id":"4",
                    "UserImage":"",
                    "Fullname":"Test4",
                    "Username":"te4"
                 }],
                 "Post":[{
                    "Post_Id":"4",
                    "UploadFile":"",
                    "Post_Caption":"Test4",
                    "User_Id":"4"
                 }],
                 "likedetails":[{
                    "Post_Id":"4",
                    "LikeCount":"3454"
                 }],
                 "commentdetails":[
                    {
                       "Comments":"testA",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testB",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testC",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testD",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testE",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    }
                 ]
              }
           ]
        },
        {
           "User_Id":5,
           "Username":"te",
           "Records":[
              {
                 "Profile":[{
                    "User_Id":"5",
                    "UserImage":"",
                    "Fullname":"Test5",
                    "Username":"te5"
                 }],
                 "Post":[{
                    "Post_Id":"5",
                    "UploadFile":"",
                    "Post_Caption":"Test5",
                    "User_Id":"5"
                 }],
                 "likedetails":[{
                    "Post_Id":"5",
                    "LikeCount":"3455"
                 }],
                 "commentdetails":[
                    {
                       "Comments":"testA",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testB",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testC",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testD",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    },
                    {
                       "Comments":"testE",
                       "Username": "te",
                       "Comment_Date":"12-12-12"
                    }
                 ]
              }
           ]
        }
     ]
  }


let arr=[];
Object.keys(Json.AllPost).forEach((records, index) => {

        Json.AllPost[records].forEach((obj, idx) => {
           arr.push(obj);
           console.log(arr);
        })
    });
```

[image: Just like above image]

ex:
codepen:https://codepen.io/dotnet345/pen/oNXBxBM

Comment: Add some code about what you have achieved till now would be great help.

Comment: where's the view?

Comment: Adding clear expected output will probably help provide an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const renderData = Json.AllPost.map((user) => {
      return user.Records.map(record =>{
        return record.Profile.map(profile =>{
           return  record.Post.map(post =>{
              return record.likedetails.map(like => {
                 return record.commentdetails.map(comment => {
              })
             })
          })
        })
      })
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this? [Card view](http://borz.surge.sh/)

```
const BASE_URL = 'https://www.instagram.com/'userName'/?__a=1';
    Axios.get(BASE_URL)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges[0].node.edge_media_to_caption.edges[0].node)
            this.setState({d: res.data.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges})
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok.

you can follow this code

```
    state={
    instagramPost: [],
}

componentDidMount() {
    const BASE_URL = 'https://www.instagram.com/'userName'/?__a=1';
    Axios.get(BASE_URL)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges[0].node.edge_media_to_caption.edges[0].node)
            this.setState({d: res.data.graphql.user.edge_owner_to_timeline_media.edges})
        });
        }

render() {
    const { instagramPost } = this.state;
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            {
    instagramPost && instagramPost.map((user, i) => (
    <div key={i}>
    <img alt="" src={user.node.edge_media_to_caption.edges[0].node.text}/>
    <div>{user.node.edge_media_to_caption.edges[0].node.text}</div>
                               </div>
    ))
            }
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have the nested array to loop through, you can try below method to get the values likes, comments and other details of each reocrd.

This might not be the best way to solve. But I'm sure it will help you. Thanks.

```js
Json.AllPost.map( post => 
Object.values(post).map( record => 
record.map( item => 
console.log(item))))
```

In the above snippet you can directly get the property values by accessing item.propertyName.

ex: item.Post